# How can I specify terms of a match in a regular expression but only capture part of the match?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to match any `abc` so long as it does not follow `x`.

I would be inclined to use the regular expression `/[^x]abc/`, but then if I write `dabc` it matches `dabc`, while I want it to only match the `abc` part.

How can I use something like `[^x]` to qualify the start of the regular expression without it counting in my match?

Comment: Or is this not possible?

Comment: Give some sample string and expected outputs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use Negative Lookbehind

You can use a negative lookbehind, and then access the last match through the special variable `$&`. For example:

```
domatch = 'foo abc'
nomatch = 'xabc'
pattern = /(?<!x)abc/

domatch.match pattern
$&
#=> "abc"

nomatch.match pattern
$&
#=> nil
```

See the [Regexp class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html) for details.

Comment: +1 this is the way. It's the difference between not matching an x and matching a non-x if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Adding () will create a matching group that you can reference:

```
a = 'dabc'
p a.match(/[^x](abc)/)[1]

=> "abc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the square brackets and then as a second argument specify the subgroup, in this case w only have one, so 1 will get the subgroup.

```
my_string = 'dabc'
my_string[/[^x](abc)/, 1] # => 'abc'
```